# How to get all the milestones under a project and its child project in rally?

Tags: web-services, rally, milestone

Is there any way to get all milestones under a project and its sub projects by using their web service?

I read in some other answers that they have deprecated `targetProject` attribute in milestone, and no longer should be used.

I have tried with using a filter like `Projects contains /project/<<project_id>>`, but it does not return the milestones where all the projects in the workspace are selected.

Is there any way to get all the milestones under a project and its sub projects, plus the milestones where all the projects are selected using their web service?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

(Projects.Name contains "name or part of name of project")

It seems to work.

Or, and this is not at all clear from the manuals:

(Projects.OID = 306375509124)

This only gets you the milestones that are valid for that particular project.

Milestones are not automatically available in the sub-projects, so you would have to traverse the project hierarchy, asking for milestones for each node.